# Rails rails-money undefined method `cents'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, money-rails

I am attempting to implement money-rails  and I have run into the following error:

> undefined method `cents' for "1,000.00":String

I followed [this tutorial](https://firmhouse.com/blog/fancy-money-entry-for-your-rails-app-with-autonumeric-and-moneyrails/) to get a "fancy" currency input field.

DB schema:

```
t.integer  "balance_cents",    default: 0,     null: false
t.string   "balance_currency", default: "USD", null: false
```

Model:

```
monetize :balance_cents, as: :balance, allow_nil: :true, :numericality => { :greater_than_or_equal_to => 0}

def initialize(attributes = {})
  super
  @balance = attributes[:balance]
end
```

Form:

```
<%= form_for(@asset, url: assets_new_path) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :balance, "Balance / Value ($)" %>
  <%= f.number_field :balance, data: { role: 'money', a_sep: ',', a_dec: '.' }, class: 'form-control' %>
```

Controller:

```
def create
  @asset = Asset.new(asset_params)
  if @asset.save
    flash[:success] = "New asset created successfully."
    redirect_to assets_path
  else
    ...
  end
end

def asset_params
  params.require(:asset).permit(:balance)
end
```

Should I be setting up the :balance input field another (better) way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#after-initialize-and-after-find) the best way to do it in the `after_initialize` callback.

Comment: I removed the override of `initialize` from my model and that seems to have done the trick. I will be honest, I had that in there because I originally followed Michael Hartl's rails tutorial and he did that for one of his models. I don't fully understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Use balance_satangs for your column instead of balance_cents